# How do I use Pandas to find the right information from my DataFrame?

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I want to know how to use pandas methods to figure out how to implement the instructions in the commented line. I have tried several different things, but I usually end up getting more confused and deleting the code after. I'm a beginner, and this is my first pandas project.

Basically, I need to count the amount of TOTAL trees in NYC, the amount of a specific type in NYC and then the same for all the boroughs. I know I haven't provided all the information, but I was hoping for help with a new way to approach this since I'm kind of lost. (Data is pulled from CSV into the df)

```
def formatInfo(matched_trees):
    for x in matched_trees:
        print(f"Entry: {x}")
        total=0
        for tree in Tree_data['spc_common']:
            if x==tree:
                total+=1
        print(f"Total number of trees:{total} ")
    
        #Needs to print percentage of matched tree of all trees in NYC. Also print percentages corresponding to each borough.
```

I tried looping through every row in the data frame but I could not figure out how to get the other information associated with the tree species. I have tried implementing multiple methods that I found online but with no success.

sample input and output:
[sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CwagT.png)

Comment: What is the format of the DataFrame? If possible, include a sample input and output in your question.

Comment: @Shorn I just updated it with an image of example output.

Comment: Are you using [`2015StreetTreesCensus_TREES.csv`](https://data.cityofnewyork.us/Environment/2015-Street-Tree-Census-Tree-Data/pi5s-9p35)?  If so, how do you want to handle unidentified trees/stumps?  What about dead trees?

Answer (score 0):

if your 'matched_trees' is a list, you can do the folowing:

```
specs = set(Tree_data['spc_common'].unique())
matched_tree_counts = {spec: matched_trees.count(spec) for spec in specs}
for spec, count in matched_tree_counts:
    print("{}% of matched trees are {}".format(count/len(matched_trees)*100:.2f, spec)
```